# Robotframework, How to define a dynamic variable name

Tags: robotframework, rpa, dynamic-variables

I want to Define variable having dynamic name.

For example

```
${${FILE}{VAR}}    Create List      // ${FILE} = TEST, ${VAR} = VAR
```

Then I want to get variable named `'${TESTVAR}'`.

Here is my Summarized code...

```
*** Settings ***

Library    SeleniumLibrary

Library    ExcelLibrary

Library    Collections

*** Variables ***

${VAR}=     VAR

*** Keywords ***

Open Document And Assign Variable

    [Arguments]     ${FILE}

    Open Excel Document filename=${FILE}    doc_id=doc_var


    ${${FILE}${VAR}}    Create List    # It doesn't work ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible with Robot Framework. You can use "variables inside variables" to resolve the values of variables (see [the documentation on this topic](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables-inside-variables)) but not to resolve/set the name of the variable itself.

Though I am afraid that would be confusing anyway. Maybe you can explain your motivations and people can come up with another solution for your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer is not really accurate.
This can be achieved exactly with robot's "Variables inside variables" feature like so:

```
FOR  ${idx}  IN RANGE  3
   ${var_name} =  Catenate  SEPARATOR=_  var  ${idx}
   Set Suite Variable  ${${var_name}}  ${idx}
END
```

you get:
   var_1=1 
   var_2=2 
   var_3=3

Please note that variables resolution is happening only for keywords arguments (at least for robot version 3.1.2 that I am using), therefore either one of 'Set test variable', 'Set Suite Variable' or 'Set Global Variable' keywords must be used. The following won't work:

```
FOR  ${idx}  IN RANGE  3
   ${var_name} =  Catenate  SEPARATOR=_  var  ${idx}
   ${${var_name}} =  ${idx}
END
```

results in: 
    No keyword with name '${${var_name}} =' found.

For your list case you just need to create a list variable and reassign it to dynamically named variable using the above mentioned keywords